# Sending a PHP email with attachment (failure)

Tags: php, email, path, email-attachments

**Background**

I'm trying to send emails with attachments using a PHP script (PHP 5.4.16). Eventually I'll be trying to get it to work in Drupal, but for now it's standalone.

**Problem**

I'm trying to implement this [script](https://github.com/ngmaloney/Attachment-Email/blob/master/attachment_email.php), which will send emails with attachments, the relevant blog is [here](http://www.metachunk.com/blog/sending-e-mails-attachments-drupal-7).

I'm running the following code, which calls the script above. The file it's trying to send is dom.txt in the same folder.

```
require_once('attachment_email.php');

$to="xxxxx@gmail.com";
$from="xxxxx@gmail.com";
$subject="Check out this report!";
$message="Yo! Check out this report!";
$attachment = array(
  'url' => 'dom.txt',
  'filename' => 'dom.txt',
);

print_r($attachment);

$email = new AttachmentEmail($to, $from, $subject, $message, $attachment);
$email->send();
```

The email arrives fine but the attachment doesn't work and I get the following errors.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'path' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 77
Warning: file_get_contents(d): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 77
Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 81
Warning: Illegal string offset 'path' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 81
Warning: Illegal string offset 'path' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 77
Warning: file_get_contents(d): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 77
Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 81
Warning: Illegal string offset 'path' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 81
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the path but I have no idea what. What am I doing wrong?

**What I've Tried**

```
'path' => 'dom.txt',
'path' => './dom.txt',
'url' => 'http://localhost/tutorials/dom.txt',
```

And all sorts of variations like that, but I'm blundering really.

I started printing out variables from `public function get_binary_attachments()` in the script above to see where it's going wrong and printing $attachment gives:

```
Array ( [url] => ./dom.txt 
        [filename] => dom.txt )
```

But $attachment_bin is empty, so something breaks there. But it might still be related to path.

EDIT --

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
  73 public function get_binary_attachments() {
  74   $output = '';
  75   foreach($this->attachments as $attachment) {
  76  
  77     echo $attachment;
  78
  79     $attachment_bin = file_get_contents($attachment['path']);
  80     $attachment_bin = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment_bin));
  81   
  82     dpm($attachment_bin);
  83     $output .= '--'. $this->boundary . PHP_EOL;
  84     $output .= 'Content-Type: '. $attachment['type'] .'; name="'. basename($attachment['path']) .'"' . PHP_EOL;
  85     $output .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . PHP_EOL;
  86     $output .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  87     $output .= $attachment_bin . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  88   }
  89   return $output;
  90 }
  91}
```

EDIT -- New Solutions tried:

1. Changing attachment to the following array add's three new lines of errors :

   ```
   'path' => 'dom.txt',
   'type'=>'text/plain',
   'filename' => 'dom.txt',
   ```

   Warning: file_get_contents(d): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 77
   Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 81
   Warning: Illegal string offset 'path' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 81
2. Using `'path' => './dom.txt'`, changes the file_get_contents errors to:

   Warning: file_get_contents(.): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\attachment_email.php on line 77
3. Changing the array to below, also does nothing.

   ```
   'path'=>'./dom.txt',
   'type'=>'MIME/type'
   ```

Comment: What's line 77 and line 81?

Comment: Good point. Added the relevant script function, with code numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing to find your attachments (it is looking for them in `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\`). Where are your files located in relation to the script? If they were in your root directory, you should be able to prefix the attachment path with something like this:

```
$attachment = array(
  'url' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dom.txt',
  'filename' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dom.txt',
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the attachment is in `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\  ` It's full path is `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorials\dom.txt`.

Comment: I see on the blog site there are others with the same problem, apparently the 'path' should be a full link with file name, and 'filename' needs setting (with only the filename and extension): ` $attachment = array(); $attachment[] = array( 'path' => '~/documents/report.pdf', 'filename' => 'report.pdf', 'type' => 'application/pdf', );`. Hope this helps

Comment: No such luck, I'd tried that and not mentioned it, my bad. It does add three new lines of errors though so I added it to the main post.

Comment: I have to ask, is there any particular reason you need to use this mail library? PHPMailer is my favourite, and I expect many would agree. It's simple and works very well: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: PHPMailer did work on a standalone site. I ended up switching back to the Drupal module Mimemail though when I managed to find a working version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an obvious thing, but according to the actual code of the script you are using `$attachments` should an array of the following structure:

```
$attachments=array(
    array( // Attachment 1
        'path'=>'/path/to/file',
        'type'=>'MIME/type',
    ),
    array( // Attachment 2
    ),
    ...
);`
```

Which is not what is stated in the documentation to the script.

Comment: I changed the variable to $attachment**s** and tried the new array (separately and together) but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I solved this by tinkering with Mimemail the Drupal module. If anyone finds this looking for Drupal help I would recommend using the Mimemail dev version (the alpha didn't work, it has a frustrating bug where the email only sends 80% of the time (as of 1st Sep '13) and this tutorial:

http://rapiddg.com/blog-post/drupal-7-html-e-mail-pdf-attachments.

Otherwise I'd go with Alfie's suggestion and use the PHPMailer library which I got working and didn't use.

(I used http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html, a little wordy but doesn't leave stuff out.)

Answer (score -1):

> I think you should try this one its work,
>   this is my php code i am using sendgrid api v3 php because its not spam email

```
$Email_to = $_POST['email']; //from html user entered email
$file_name = $_FILES["upload-file-name"]['name']; //from html upload file it should be less then 2MB 
$tmp_name = $_FILES['upload-file-name']["tmp_name"];
require 'sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $file_name));
/*$uploadfile is use for user can upload file from any dir. if you are not using you can got error ="file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory php email attachment"*/
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploadfile)) {


$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("xxxxxx@xxx.com");
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo($Email_to);  //send email to user entered email address in form
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);

$file_encoded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($uploadfile)); $email->addAttachment(
    $file_encoded,
    "application/pdf",
    "customized-file-name.pdf", //you can also add file name as it is like $file_name
    "attachment" );
```

> htlm

```
    <form method="POST" id="form" action="test-sandgrid.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<!--enctype is mendetory to upload files-->
        <div class="container" style="width:auto!important">
            <h1 style="text-transform:none ; text-align: center">eCatalog Enquiry Form</h1>
            <p>Please fill in this form to submit your information.</p>
            <hr>
            <label for="file"><b>Upload CV </b></label><br>
            <input type="file" name="" class="form-control" accept=".pdf" value="photo" required/><br>  
<!--name="upload-file-name"is mendetory , accept is optional i allowed to upload only .pdf file from user and when user select upload file olny .pdf file shows-->


            <label for="email"><b>Email address</b></label><br>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required /><br>

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit Your Enquiry</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```